# Calculating percentage of better hand.

Tags: probability, percentages

For example, I have two cards and there are two other players. They have both 20% chance of having a better hand then me, how much chance is it in total that either one of them has a better hand then mine?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It means you have a hand that's worse EITHER than the first OR than a second, so don't count twice:

$$
P(A \cup B) = P(A) +P(B) - P(A \cap B)
$$

If these probabilities are independent, you have $P( A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Comment: Is there any chance you can do an example for me? Im not really good with formulas. Oh, and there is obviously a chance that they both get lucky and have a better hand than I have.

Comment: $P(A)$: the chance player 1 has a better hand, $P(B)$: the chance the second player has a better hand, $P(A \cup B)$: the chance EITHER player has a better hand, $P(A \cap B)$: the chance both players have a btter hand.

Comment: I still dont know how to solve this. A and B are both 0.2 or 20 in this case right?

Comment: yes it's $0.2$.

Comment: So how do I solve this? I have tried putting it in an editor such as mathway.com, but entering P(0.2∩0.2) does not work.

Comment: did you read my comments above? $P(A \cap B) = P(A) P(B)$ if these events are independent

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really am not getting the point on how to really calculate this. Is there any online tool you recommend to do this?

Comment: Probabilty (what you need) = 0.2 +0.2 -0.2*0.2. Is this clear now?

Comment: Yeah, this makes sense. How would we calculate this if there were 9 players in total? So me and 8 other players, what are the odds that atleast one of them has a better hand?